# How can I replace a word with its root in postgresql?

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, regexp-replace

what I would like to do is something like

```
select
"wise, wisdom and wiseness have a common root"  as body,
regexp_replace(body,'wis%','wise')
```

to obtain

```
wise --> wise  
wisdom --> wise   
wiseness --> wise
```

and so the result would be
"wise, wise and wise have a common root"

Comment: How would you computationally go from "wisdom" to "wise"? It's not that trivial and probably too broad for a StackOverflow question.

Comment: From a linguistic pow I agree, but here it would be enough to go from wis --> to wisdom, which is much easier. I'm not caring about mistakes like 'I wish you're fine' --> 'I wise you're fine'

Comment: Does this need to work with other roots or just specifically with "wis"?

Comment: Just with a specific root. Actually the first comment is exactly what I meant, it was much easier than I thought

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14064547/9990662.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=55573404e7f1f5c23e8ce31d26f59060)

```
select
regexp_replace('wise, wisdom and wiseness have a common root','wis[\w]*','wise','g')
```

1. RegExp `wis[\w]*` is searching for all words beginning with wis followed by any number of letters and digits. Use `[A-Za-z]` instead of `[\w]` if you only are interested in letters.
2. Flag `g` makes it for all occurences.